# code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV), I am begginer in C

Tags: c

I am beginner in C. I want to get sum of all elements per column from bidimensional array and put in another onedimensinal array. When compilator tries to make that, it gives error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



int** allocArrayMatrix ( int nl, int nc);
void showArrayMatrix(int ** a, int nl, int nc);
void formArray(int ** a, int nl, int nc);
int SumArray(int ** a, int nl, int nc);
void freeMemoryArray(int** a, int nl);



int main() {
    int **a, nl=10, nc=10;
    int f;
    int *p;


    a = allocArrayMatrix(nl, nc);

    if (a == NULL) {
        puts("Memoria p/u tabloul 2-D nu a fost alocata");
    }
    else {
        puts("Memoria a fost alocata cu succes");

    }

   formArray(a,nl,nc);
   printf("\nTablul bidimensional format:\n ");
   showArrayMatrix(a,nl,nc);

   p =  SumArray(a, nl,nc );
    for (f=0;f<nc;f++){
       printf("%d\t",*(p+f));
   }
   freeMemoryArray(a,nl);









}
int ** allocArrayMatrix( int nl, int nc) {
    int i;
    int** a=(int **)malloc(nl*sizeof (int*));
    if (a==NULL) return a;
    for (i=0; i<nl ;i++)
    {a[i] =(int*)malloc(nc*sizeof(int));
        if (a[i]==NULL) return NULL;
    }
    return a;
}

void showArrayMatrix(int ** a, int nl, int nc)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<nl;i++){
        for (j=0;j<nc;j++) {

            printf ("%d\t", a[i][j] );}
        printf("\n"); }
    return;
}

void formArray(int ** a, int nl, int nc)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<nl;i++){
        for (j=0;j<nc;j++)
            a[i][j] = rand()%100-50 ;
    }
    return;
}
int SumArray(int ** a, int nl, int nc)
{int i,j, Sum;
    static int  b[10];

for (i=0; i<nc; i++){
    Sum = 0;
    for (j=0;j<nl;j++){
        Sum = Sum + a[j][i];

    }

    b[i] = Sum;

}

    return b;

}
void freeMemoryArray(int** a, int nl) {
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < nl; i++) {
        free(a[i]);
    }


     free(a);
}
```

That is output

```
Memoria a fost alocata cu succes

Tablul bidimensional format:
 33 36  27  -35 43  -15 36  42  -1  -29 
12  -23 40  9   13  -24 -10 -24 22  -14 
-39 18  17  -21 32  -20 12  -27 17  -15 
-21 -48 -28 8   19  17  43  6   -39 -8  
-21 23  -29 -31 34  -13 48  -26 -35 20  
-37 -24 41  30  6   23  12  20  46  31  
-45 -25 34  -23 -14 -45 -4  -21 -37 7   
-26 45  32  -5  -36 17  -16 14  -7  0   
37  -42 26  28  38  34  -47 1   4   49  
-18 10  26  18  -11 -38 -24 36  44  -11 

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Where is the problem? I find that comes from incorrect memory allocation, but I couldn't solve this problem

Comment: Please check out the compiler warning for lines 34 and 95 about differing levels of indirection.

Comment: Aside: you are calling `rand()` so when you move past the debugging stage I suggest you put `srand(time(NULL))` at the beginning of `main()` to call once only. For now though, the program course is repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of this function is incorrect : it must return a pointer to an int instead of an int :

```
int * SumArray(int ** a, int nl, int nc);
```